# Simulate keypress using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, keypress

I want to simulate an keypress with jQuery.

I already tried this:

```
$("#canvas").trigger( jQuery.Event( 'keypress', { keyCode: 87, which: 87 }) );
```

But nothing's happening.

Full code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 49) {

        $("#canvas").trigger( jQuery.Event( 'keypress', { keyCode: 87, which: 87 }) );

    }

});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you tried this code in page load event ?

Comment: I am doing it with the keydown event.

Comment: yeah, and where `keydown` event is declared ? in page load or domready ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this one:

You can create an [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
$('#canvas').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 87, which: 13}));
```

You maybe have to try which parameter to set, e.g. `keyCode.`

or

The real answer has to include `keyCode:`

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
e.keyCode = 50
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Even though jQuery's website says that which and keyCode are normalized they are very badly mistaken. It's always safest to do the standard cross-browser checks for e.which and e.keyCode and in this case just define both.

or

jQuery has a `.keypress` method accepting no arguments that simulates a keypress.

```
$("#canvas").keypress();
```

Will trigger a keypress on `#canvas`

If you'd like to also select which key was pressed, you can use `.trigger`. This example is from the [Docs.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 87}); //"keydown" if that's what you're doing
$("body").trigger(e);
```

The key code 87 is the [Key code backspace](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)  in javascript

Let me know how that works for you :)

My demo pages:

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/DxER9/594/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/z24Um/431/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The problem was that i triggered the wrong element!

Answer (score 0):

here is a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/r4z6szg5/) it works

```
var e = $.Event('keypress');
e.which = 87;
$('#canvas').trigger(e);
```